# Cycle.js: Custom driver not emitting any event inside main()

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I'm creating a custom [cycle.js](https://cycle.js.org/drivers.html) driver with the purpose of preloading images. The main function exports a sink stream `imagesToLoad` emitting an array of image URLs. Those are then loaded by the driver and **should** return a stream that emits when the images are finished loading.

### Problem

I can subscribe to the stream returned by the driver inside the driver's code and see that the loaded images are indeed emitted **but never when mapping from inside the main function**.

I am probably doing something wrong but I cannot see what exactly.

#### The driver

```js
import { from, Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { adapt } from '@cycle/run/lib/adapt'

const loadImage = (src) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new Image()
        img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img))
        img.addEventListener('error', (err) => reject(err))
        img.src = src
    })

export const makeImageLoaderDriver = () => {

    const imageLoaderDriver = (sink$) => {
        const imageCache = {}
        const source$ = new Subject()

        from(source$).subscribe({
            next(images) {
                const imagesPromises = images.map((src) => {
                    const imgSuccess = { src, loaded: true }
                    if (!!imageCache[src]) return Promise.resolve(imgSuccess)
                    return loadImage(src)
                        .then(() => {
                            imageCache[src] = imgSuccess
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            imageCache[src] = { src, loaded: false, error }
                        })
                })

                Promise.all(imagesPromises).then(() => {
                    source$.next(imageCache)
                })
            },
        })

        return adapt(source$)
    }

    return imageLoaderDriver
}
```

#### The index.js

```js
const drivers = {
    imagesToLoad: makeImageLoaderDriver(),
}

run(main, drivers)
```

#### The main function

```js
export function main(sources) {

    sources.imagesToLoad.pipe(map(console.log)) // THIS NEVER LOGS ANYTHING

    return {
        imagesToLoad: of([ imageUrl1, imageUrl2 ]),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sources.imagesToLoad.pipe(map(console.log))` creates a new Observable, but this Observable is not named (as a `const`) and is not used anywhere else. It's just dropped and never subscribed to, so effectively that line in `main` does nothing.

It needs to get plugged into one of the other stream pipelines that will some way end up in the **sink**. For instance, get the output of that operation, name it as a `const`, and then use that `const` stream in another stream pipeline, and this stream pipeline must eventually end up in a sink.

To debug, you can put `.subscribe()` after the `map`, and most likely you will see the `console.log` happen. Just don't leave the `subscribe()` in the code because Cycle.js is a framework where you don't ever need to subscribe on the `main` side, because subscriptions are meant for the drivers side.

Notice also that your driver takes `sink$` as input but it never uses that. You should subscribe to `sink$` and perform effects based on its emissions.

Comment: Right! That's it! I knew I missed something. This optimization completely makes sense! Thank you! 

Regarding the unused `sink$`, it was a mistake, the part where I call `from(source$)` should be `from(sink$)`. Thank you for pointing out this mistake as well! 

Comment: Apart from my question. Do you think this driver makes sense and should I publish it as a npm package?

Comment: I'll answer my own question haha: Here is it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cycle-image-loading-driver